# JQuery event kills rails's link

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I just noticed that My links wouldn't work after jquery event happened... 
What I want to do is that make a div bigger and swap contents. After the event happen, Rails link_to and render 'form' stop working...
How can I fix this problem and If you know why that's happening, would you explain why ?

JQuery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".readmore").on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $id = $(this).attr("id");
    var $target_id = "#post-"+$id; 
    var $long = ".long-"+$id;
    var $short = ".short-"+$id;
    jQuery(".flex-cube").toggle(
        function () {
            jQuery($target_id).animate({marginRight: 0,width:"490px" }, 1000, "easeInOutQuad")
        },
        function () {                
            jQuery($target_id).animate({marginRight: 0,width:"490px" }, 1000, "easeInOutQuad")                   
        }  
    );    
    jQuery($target_id).addClass(".extended");
    jQuery($long).fadeIn(1000);
    jQuery($short).fadeOut(1000);
    return;
});
```

});

HTML & RoR code

```
<div class="flex-cube rounded-corner white-bk">
    <div id="form"><%= render 'form' %></div>
</div>
<% @microposts.each do |post|%>
    <div id="post-<%= post.id%>" class="flex-cube rounded-corner white-bk">
        <h5 class="black_bk white_font tenpx-padding"><%= post.username %></h5>
        <spam>
            <%= image_tag(post.image_url(:thumb)) if post.image?%>
            <% if post.posts.length > 250 %>
                <div class="short-<%=post.id%> active"><%= post.posts.slice(0..250)%>
                    <div id="<%= post.id%>" class="readmore button small post-<%= post.id%>">[-- Read More --]</div>
                </div>
                <div class="long-<%=post.id%> inactive">
                    <%= post.posts%>
                </div>

            <% else %>
                <div class="short-<%=post.id%> active"><%= post.posts%></div>
            <%end%>
        </spam>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
event.preventDefault();
```

That line prevents the default actions from happening. See this question for a good explanation: [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false).